# Position of the soft keyboard in Android

Tags: jquery, html, android-softkeyboard

I want to get soft keyboard as popup right below the input element whenever it is clicked. My exact situation is when I click input element(on android smartphone) the whole page(i.e the entire DOM) goes up to make room for the softkeyboard. I don't want this behavior.
what I wanted is, softkeyboard should open as popup without moving the actual page.

Is there any way to do this? I tried lot with changing position attribute but nothing worked.

This is my code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"  data-theme="a" style="background-color:white">
        <!--header-->
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <img src="img/hd.jpg" style="width:100%;z-index:0;">
            <p><strong>BOOKing ONLINE</strong></p>
            <a href="#splash" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-shadow="false" class="ui-btn ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-carat-l" >Back</a>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars">Menu</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer" style="margin: 19% 0% 0% 0%">
            <center>
                <form>
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <legend></legend>
                    <input type="radio"  name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="on" checked="checked">
                    <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">Domestic</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="off">
                    <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">International</label>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </center>
        </div>
        <div style="margin:9% 0% 0% 0%">
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-b center" style="margin:6% 0% 0% 0%">
            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#pin_list" id="pin1" data-transition="slideup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all" >From</a></div>
            <div id="fromto" class="ui-block-b" style="margin: 0% -20% 0% 11%"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-r ui-state-disabled ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all" style="filter: Alpha(Opacity=90);opacity: .9;">No text</a>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c"><a href="#pin_list" id="pin2" data-transition="slideup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-shadow ui-corner-all">To</a></div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin:6% 0% 0% 0%">
            <hr>
        </div>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" align='center' style="margin:7% 0% 0% 0%">
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-alt-icon ui-icon-mail ui-btn-icon-left ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-active">mail</a>
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-alt-icon ui-icon-shop ui-btn-icon-left ui-nodisc-icon">shop</a>
        </div>
        <div style="margin:6% 0% 0% 0%">
            <hr>
        </div>
        <table id="weightTable">
            <tr >
                <td style="text-align:right;width:40%">WEIGHT</td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><input data-type="number" type="number" value="0.5" id="weight"></td>
                <td style="text-align:left;width:40%">kg</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div align=center style="margin:2% 0% 0% 0%">
            <a id='getq' class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-nodisc-icon">GET</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="navbar" align=center style="margin:2% 0% 0% 0%;width:100%;">
            <ul>
                        <li ><a href="#">menu</a></li>
                        <li style="width:50%"><a href="#track" data-transition="slideup" class="ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-top ui-nodisc-icon">Track</a></li>
                        <li style="width:25%"><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-alt-icon ui-icon-bullets ui-btn-icon-top ui-nodisc-icon">More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can find one input field at `#weightTable` when I tap that element the whole page moves up, below the navabar the softkeyboard appears. I want to appear it right below the input field by hiding the contents after it. Please help me.

this is the img:

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. When they keyboard appears it actually reduces the height of your visible window as well. I'm guessing they did this so that the keyboard does not overlay the content and make parts of the page inaccessible. 

Having said that, are you having trouble with the keyboard not appearing directly under the input that is focused? Any chance you can upload an image?

Comment: @JohnP I added the image. you can see that the sofkeyboard is below the navabar. it is suppose to be below the input field.

Comment: It is below the input field... If you want to, you could create a css rule that hides the navbar when the window goes below a certain height (depending on orientation and device resolution) since window resize is what happens when the softkeyboard is shown.

Comment: Also, you might want to test this behaviour in multiple browsers. The newer android phones generally have chrome as the default browser and not the older android native browser.

Comment: @JohnP sorry to mention this that the above code is part cordova mobile app project. I think browser is nothing to do with this